# Setting the Culture for the rest of the request in an Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, globalization, culture

Our application shows invoice data, so the URL is something like https://localhost/Invoices/guid-goes-here

So in the Action handling this request, I retrieve the Invoice data. Included in this data is the culture that was used in the shop.

Displaying the invoice data (and consequently paying the invoice) is a separate web application, and I want to set the Culture of the Views used to display the invoice to use the Culture that matches the Invoice.

However, the only sort of work-around I've found so far to set Culture per request is using middleware reading the culture from the URL. I don't want the culture in the URL.

I haven't found a way to do this. Is this possible in the new asynchronous way aspnet core works? I'm using .Net 5

What I want:

```
public class InvoiceController
{
  [Route("{id}"]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Guid id)
  {
    var invoice = await _apiClient.InvoiceAsync(id);

    // Here is what I want to do
    SetCultureTo(invoice.Culture);

    // Views and partials should now all have culture settings for resources
    return View(invoice);
  }
}
```

But because the method is async, and all the views are rendered on different thread, simply setting the CurrentCulture won't do what I want it to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-a-custom-provider-2

Comment: Could you please add some code of how it works for you, and you want it to be

Comment: @KirkLarkin That's what I've used to get what I have, which is a middleware option that reads the culture from the URL that is requested, and sets it then.  What I want is a way to set it from the action in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the culture directly by assigning `CultureInfo` params as below:

```cs
public void SetCulture(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
}
```

And if you want to revert back to the original culture, create a class that will do the switch and reverting:

```cs
public sealed class CultureSwitcher : IDisposable
{
    private readonly CultureInfo _originalCulture;

    public CultureSwitcher(string culture)
    {
        _originalCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        var cultureInfo = String.IsNullOrEmpty(culture) 
                          ? CultureInfo.CurrentCulture 
                          : new CultureInfo(culture);

        SetCulture(cultureInfo);
    }

    private void SetCulture(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        SetCulture(_originalCulture);
    }
}
```

And use it like below:

```cs
using(var cs = new CultureSwitcher("en"))
{
    // do what ever in the specified culture...
}
// here it will be reverted back to the original culture
```

Reference:

- https://github.com/joakimriedel/culture-switcher/blob/master/src/CultureSwitcher.cs

Comment: It doesn't work :( In my views the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture are reset back to default after setting it in the Action. The DefaultThreadCurrentCulture remains set properly, but was null at the point where I'm setting this, and does not seem to have any impact.

Comment: Can you provide more details in your question? add some code of what you have done?

Comment: I added a bit of code that looks like what I want to achieve, ideally. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the result I want, but not in the way that I want. And it's probably not as robust as it should be, but it works for my scenario.

So I did end up using the middleware option.

Something that earlier didn't click with me (I'm fairly new to .Net Core) was how the different Startup.cs methods:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {}
```

and

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
```

interact.

All examples I've found, suggest doing something like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
  {
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = ...;
    options.SupportedCultures = ...;
    options.SupportedUICultures = ...;
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Add(new CustomCultureProvider());
  });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  app.UseRequestLocalization();
}
```

And then in the provider I have implemented this method:

```
public class CustomCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
{
    public override Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(httpContext.Request.Path, "\\/[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2}\\/");
        if (!match.Success) return Task.FromResult(default(ProviderCultureResult));

        var culture = match.Value.Substring(1, 5);
        return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(culture));
    }
}
```

My problem is that I didn't have access to the API in the CultureProvider.

I've managed to work around this limitation by not setting op the RequestLocalizationOptions in the ConfigureServices method.

I created an extension method to the IApplicationBuilder

```
    public static void AddCustomCultureProvider(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = ...,
            SupportedCultures = ...,
            SupportedUICultures = ...
        };
        var httpClient = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IRestClient>();
        var apiClient = new ApiClient(httpClient);
        options.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
        options.RequestCultureProviders.Add(new CustomCultureProvider(apiClient));

        app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
    }
```

So now I can

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.AddCustomCultureProvider();
    }
```

Which will do on each request

```
public class CustomCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
{
    private readonly IApiClient _client;

    public CustomCultureProvider(IApiClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }
    public async override Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var urlParts = httpContext.Request.Path.ToString().Split(new []{ '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var invoiceId = urlParts.FirstOrDefault(p => Guid.TryParse(p, out var invoiceId));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(invoiceId))
        {
            var invoice = await _client.InvoiceAsync(new Guid(invoiceId));
            return new ProviderCultureResult(invoice.Culture);
        }
        
        return default(ProviderCultureResult);       
    }
}
```

And yeah this works! It's a bit of guesswork to get the Guid from the request path which I don't like.

I will not be marking this as an answer, since it's a work-around, not an answer. And I'm very open to suggestions on how to improve this, and of course still looking for an answer to the original question. But for now I've got this in place.